# Initialize an array of std::bitset in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, bitset

I'm trying to set all the elements in a 64-bit bitset array to 0. `std::bitset<64> map[100];`
I know i can use a loop to iterate all the elements and call .unset() on them like this.

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i< 100 ; i++){
    map[i].unset();
}
```

However, I want to know if there is a "proper" way of doing it.

Is `std::bitset<64> map[100] = {};` okay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) default constructor initializes all bits to zero, so you don't need to do anything extra other than declare the array.

```
std::bitset<64> map[100];  // each bitset has all 64 bits set to 0
```

To set all bits to one, I'd use the [`bitset::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set) member function, which has an overload that sets all bits to one. Combine this with a `for_each` to call the member function on each array element.

```
std::for_each(std::begin(map), std::end(map), 
              [](std::bitset<64>& m) { m.set(); });
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8459f7a61cf8d15)

Another solution is to initialize each array member, but this is rather tedious for a 100 element array;.

```
std::bitset<64> map[100] = {0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL, ... 99 times more};
```

Comment: Could also use `std::fill(std::begin(map), std::end(map), -1);`

Answer (score 1):

The [`default constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) of `bitset` initializes all elements to `0`. I would say the best way of initializing an array is with

```
std::bitset<64> map[100] = {};
```

as that default initiates all elements. It is also clean, clear and concise.

Comment: what if i want to set all of them to 1 instead of 0? do i do `std::bitset<64> map[100] = {1};` ?

Comment: @vincentleest that sets only `map[0][0]` to `1`. The rest are set to `0`.

Comment: Hm, since the default constructor does the job, why do it twice? It takes time.

Answer (score -2):

Also, in your code you could think that a 0 is a 1, and viceversa (only changing the logic). But only if you are able to do it.